# Detect system time and set css animation start time in browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a html page that has a simple CSS animation, nothing fancy just a background transition between two colors.

Currently I cannot seem to figure out how to get the system time and fire the animation trigger at a specified time

I want to load it in chrome on several mobile devices. Get the system time and then when a preset time is reached the animation plays on a loop.

Comment: You going to need to write some javascript to kick off the animation. Infinite loop will also be needed to check if it's time yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made an example using `animation-play-state` according to second. This adaptable any specific time.

```js
const div = document.querySelector("div");

function getTime(){
  let date = new Date();
  let second = date.getSeconds();
  console.log(second);
  
  if(second == 10){
    div.style.animationPlayState = "running";
  }
}
setInterval(function(){
  getTime();
},1);
```

```css
div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  animation:animate 2s linear infinite;
  animation-play-state:paused;
}

@keyframes animate {
  from {
    background-color: red;
  }
  to {
    background-color: blue;
  }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: That's interesting i didn't think to do it that way. How can i set the specific start time so the animations are synced? for example if you load your example into two browser tabs they are not in sync

Comment: is there a way to add milliseconds and seconds?